# Changing element in a list

Tags: python, regex, list

So given a list, e.g.

```
lines = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence.']
```

I need to remove all punctuation at the start and end of a word. In this case, the '.' from 'sentence.'.

This is what I am using at the moment:

```
lines = line.strip().split()
for l in lines:
    l = re.sub(r'^[^A-Za-z0-9]*|[^A-Za-z0-9]*$','', l)
words.append(lines)
```

I know that the regex is working (through checking it by using `print(l)` in the loop), but when I print out lines (i.e. out of the loop), the punctuation is still there! What is wrong with my code.

This is what should be appended to words:

```
lines = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

Comment: `l` is just pointing to some string in `lines`. When you write `l = ...`, all you do is change what `l` points to, leaving the underlying object unchanged (strings are immutable anyways, so you can't change them). You have to modify the actual list object using `lines[index] = ...` or create a brand new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the processed text back into the list; strings are immutable, they can't be changed in-place. For example:

```
for i, l in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = re.sub(r'^[^A-Za-z0-9]*|[^A-Za-z0-9]*$','', l)
```

or a list comprehension version:

```
lines = [re.sub(r'^[^A-Za-z0-9]*|[^A-Za-z0-9]*$','', l) for l in lines]
```

Comment: I can't say I can recommend regex here. It seems he's just stripping punctuation from the beginning and the end of words, in which case why not use `string.strip`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the mutability/immutability of the elements, but to what Blender explained in its comment. If one writes ``li = [[45,12],['a','b']] ; for l in li: l = l + [1000]`` , the object referenced by ``li`` will remain the same, that is to say its elements remain the same ones. - By the way, to keep the identifier ``lines`` binded to the same object (id est at the same adress), one must write ``lines[:] = expression``

Answer (score 1):

This seems silly...why are we using regex for this?

```
import string
lines = [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in line.split()]
```

Comment: See "line.split()" in your list comp, list objects don't have a split().

Comment: `line` is not a list, as per the original question `lines = line.strip().split()`